# localhost connection (ASP.NET MVC)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, localhost, connection-string

I've been trying to put a stored procedure in the website that I'm working on right now, I'm using ASP.NET MVC. So I decided to create a class named: RegisterRepository.cs, under the Repository folder but whenever I tried to send a registration form I always get this **localhost refused to connect** error. I've already check the connection strings but I can't see the problem. I hope someone can help me. Thank you.

This is my RegisterRepository class:

```
public class RegisterRepository
{
    private SqlConnection con;
    //To Handle connection related activities
    private void connection()
    {
        string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ToString();
        con = new SqlConnection(constr);

    }


    public bool Register(TalentInfo model)
    {
        connection();

        try
        {
            SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("SP_INSERT_TALENT_INFO", con);
            com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Talent_Name", model.Talent_Name);
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Talent_Email", model.Talent_Email);
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Talent_SelfPromotion", model.Talent_SelfPromotion);
            con.Open();
            int i = com.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
            if (i >= 1)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {

                return false;
            }


        }

        catch
        {
            return Register(model);
        }
        finally
        {
            con.Close();
        }

    }


}
```

And this is my Web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301880
  -->
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-Yes-20160608102601.mdf;Initial Catalog=aspnet-Yes-20160608102601;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="TalentInfoEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.TalentInfo.csdl|res://*/Models.TalentInfo.ssdl|res://*/Models.TalentInfo.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=GAYLE-PC\SQLEXPRESS;initial catalog=Yes.org;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="EmailPassword" value="your_password" />
    <add key="reCaptchaPublicKey" value="Your site key" />
    <add key="reCaptchaPrivateKey" value="Your secret key" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <authentication mode="None" />
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="102400" targetFramework="4.5" />
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules>
      <remove name="FormsAuthentication" />
    </modules>
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="104857600" />
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>
  </system.webServer>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-5.2.2.0" newVersion="5.2.2.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Optimization" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="1.1.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.5.2.14234" newVersion="1.5.2.14234" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="mssqllocaldb" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

My Controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private TalentInfoEntities db = new TalentInfoEntities();

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult Register()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Register(TalentInfo model, IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> files)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {

            RegisterRepository regRepo = new RegisterRepository();

            if (regRepo.Register(model))
            {
                List<string> paths = new List<string>();

                foreach (var file in files)
                {
                    if (file.ContentLength > 0)
                    {
                        var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
                        var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/uploads"), fileName);
                        file.SaveAs(path);
                        paths.Add(path);
                    }
                }

                var message = new MailMessage();
                foreach (var path in paths)
                {
                    var fileInfo = new FileInfo(path);
                    var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
                    using (var stream = fileInfo.OpenRead())
                    {
                        stream.CopyTo(memoryStream);
                    }
                    memoryStream.Position = 0;
                    string fileName = fileInfo.Name;
                    message.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(memoryStream, fileName));
                }

                //Rest of business logic here
                string EncodedResponse = Request.Form["g-Recaptcha-Response"];
                bool IsCaptchaValid = (ReCaptcha.Validate(EncodedResponse) == "True" ? true : false);
                if (IsCaptchaValid)
                {

                    var body = "<p><b>Email From:</b> {0} ({1})</p><p><b>Message:<b></p><p>{2}</p>";
                    message.To.Add(new MailAddress("***"));  // replace with valid value 
                    message.From = new MailAddress("***");  // replace with valid value
                    message.Subject = "Yes.org (REGISTRATION)";
                    message.Body = string.Format(body, model.Talent_Name, model.Talent_Email, model.Talent_SelfPromotion);
                    message.IsBodyHtml = true;
                    using (var smtp = new SmtpClient())
                    {
                        var credential = new NetworkCredential
                        {
                            UserName = "***",  // replace with valid value
                            Password = "***"  // replace with valid value
                        };
                        smtp.Credentials = credential;
                        smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
                        smtp.Port = 587;
                        smtp.EnableSsl = true;
                        smtp.SendCompleted += (s, e) =>
                        {
                            //delete attached files
                            foreach (var path in paths)
                                System.IO.File.Delete(path);
                        };
                        await smtp.SendMailAsync(message);
                        ViewBag.Message = "Your message has been sent!";

                        ModelState.Clear();
                        return View("Register");
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    TempData["recaptcha"] = "Please verify that you are not a robot!";
                }

            } return View(model);

        }

        else
        {
            return View(model);
        }
    }



}
```

Comment: What controller are you hitting? Does your Index page load?

Comment: @Larry I just add my controller Sir. :) Yes, It's loading. But when I'm trying to send the registration form I always get this: **localhost refused to connect**.

Comment: Which DB has your stored proc, DefaultConnection or TalentInfoEntities? Your connection is pointing to the former. Try ConnectionStrings["TalentInfoEntities"]

Comment: @SteveGreene  It's in the TalentInfoEntities. I tried the  ConnectionStrings["TalentInfoEntities"] Sir, then I got this error: **System.ArgumentException: Keyword not supported: 'metadata'** 
'{
string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["TalentInfoEntities"].ToString();       con = new SqlConnection(constr)     }'

Comment: Yes, you don't need the metadata for a SQL connection. Remove the garbage from that connection string: metadata=res://*/Models.TalentInfo.csdl|res://*/Models.TalentInfo.ssdl|res://*/Models.TalentInfo.msl;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing your connection string to something like this:

```
<add name="TalentInfoEntities" connectionString="Data Source=GAYLE-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Yes.org;Integrated Security=SSPI; MultipleActiveResultSets=true" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```